# В чем преимущество fastcgi микросервис над http микросервисом?

Tags: nginx, http, веб-сервер, микросервисы, fastcgi

К примеру у меня есть вебсервер на базе `nginx`, который использует микросервис (написанный на `c++`) для обработки некоторых данных от пользователя. Так вот, мне не совсем понятно в чем состоит преимущество реализации этого микросервиса через `fastcgi` а не как `http` сервера (например с помощью `boost::beast` и `boost::asio`). Заранее спасибо

Comment: [Несколько](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431309/fastcgi-or-http-server-for-c-daemon-behind-nginx-proxy?rq=1) [аналогичных](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003714/nginx-and-perl-fastcgi-vs-reverse-proxy-psgi-starman) [вопросов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032666/why-implement-a-web-application-as-fastcgi-rather-than-a-new-web-server) на enSO, если ещё не видел... хотя чего-то абсолютно убедительного там нет...

Comment: Да в общем-то без разницы. Разве что протокол FastCGI проще чем HTTP, но в реальности вы всё равно берёте готовую библиотеку.